# Google sheets: Easily convert delimited contact notes to specific columns

Tags: google-sheets

Previously, we were storing all contacts to people who call us in a single cell called Notes. Now, we are going to be storing each contact or attempted contact in its own cell in a column called "Touchpoint #n." I know how to use the =split() function to break cells by a specified delimiter, I'm wondering if there might be an easy way to do this across an entire sheet or using an arrayformula or something like that.

[Here is an example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MspVxTLWWrqr-ZEWhKU7q9knthg-n3D_cgGIz83cupo/edit#gid=624220309). The sheet in question is "SPLIT." AC2 is an example of the former method, AH3:AM3 shows what AC2 should look like after the splitting occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can't use split with arrayformula vertically, you can you a single regexreplace and split function to cleanly separate out your data across the rows :

```
=split(join(")",split(REGEXREPLACE(AC2,"(\()(\w+ )","$2 $1"),"(")),")")
```

I added my formula to your sheet and highlighted it in green:

[image]

Updated: Per your question about the period:

```
=split(join(")",split(REGEXREPLACE(AC2,"( \()(\w+ )",". $2 $1"),"(")),")")
```

Comment: I don't understand the REGEXREPLACE() function very well - is there any way to put a "." after the word and before the initials? So rather than "LM RY" it would read "LM. RY" ?

Comment: That is exactly what we needed. Perfect. Now I guess it's time for me to go learn more about regexreplace()!